# Memory usage examination

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded

I have an embedded application compiled using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and I faced with big ram usage problem.

Using `arm-none-eabi-nm` I can find out how many memory allocates for some object. But when this object is class implementation I can't find out how many memory uses each member of class. How to know it?

It is rather hard to call `sizeof()` for each member since there are a lot of class members and there is no console for embedded application.

Comment: You can analyze extended listing from linker (with static usage). Most popular misconception with uP is that constant (if note declared in specific way) are copied from flash to RAM.

Comment: Unclear to me. Since you tagged your question [tag:c++] but you are talking about [tag:gcc], could you post an example of those "class implementation" and clarify how those members are allocated?

Comment: Sizeof class X { char * buf; } has almost nothing to RAM usage at runtime. Hard to help You in general, without code

Comment: @JacekCz and I dare you to compile `class X { char * buf; }`  with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`... ;)

Comment: There will usually be a map file spat out by the linker, which typically gives you all the details of every single thing allocated by your program.

Comment: @LPs : gcc (GNU Compiler *Collection*) is a generic term. The compiler driver *gcc* can compile C and C++, differing from g++ only in the default standard library implicitly linked, which is often overridden in any case in bare metal embedded systems.  My point being that there is no inconsistency with tagging gcc and C++.

Comment: @Clifford What I meant is that the tag is `C++` but the body of question is talking about `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, that I know can be used with `.cpp` files and adding `stdc++`, but leave the question unclear. So I asked to post the code to clarify what OP is really doing: real `C++` code or something like object oriented programming using `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the linker generate memory map file. Mostly It will be ".map extension".

In many IDE by default disable and because of this linker doesn't generates this file in that case you have to enable it from project setting.

Comment: Assuming you find the .map file, what do you do with it? Is is just a text file with a list of objects and their size?

Comment: typically map file gives all the details(size, name, location, section) about memory allocated for every single thing(code, data, class, variable).